# Load Linux Kernel Modules

Tags: ubuntu, suse, modprobe

I need to load the kernel modules nandsim.ko, ubifs.ko and ubi.ko with modprobe. Unfortunately my SuSE 9.3 machine (no internet connetion!) doesn't have them, but I found them on my Ubuntu machine. Is there a way to use the .ko files from the Ubuntu machine on the SuSE?

```
insmod /absolute/path/to/module.ko
```

doesn't work....

```
"Invalid module format"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you nearly answered your own question with the `Invalid module format` error message: compiled kernel modules can normally only load on a specific kernel version and setup.

You need to find a package built for the exact system you are using.